# Dimension too large when using path to include graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, dimensions

Im trying to include an image as xy-plane on z=0. See mwe.

ymax is supposed to be 1500. But when I change ymax to 1500, the domain, `(axis cs:7.5,75,0) coordinate (P)` to `(axis cs:7.5,750,0) coordinate (P)` and `[width = 15cm, height = 150cm]` to `[width = 15cm, height = 1500cm]`, I get the error, that the dimension is too large.

Is there a solution, so I dont have to write `time/10` as ylabel?

The method of including the image is based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516987/adding-external-graphic-as-plane-in-3d-plot/516994#516994) question.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
         grid,
         enlargelimits = false,     
         xmin = 0,
         xmax = 15,
         ymin = 0,
         ymax = 150, % ymax should be 1500
         restrict x to domain*=0:15,
         restrict y to domain*=0:150, % see above
         zmin = -300,
         zmax = 0,
         ylabel = {Time / 10},
         xlabel = {x},
         zlabel = {},
         view={-30}{40},
     ]
         \path (axis cs:0,0,0) coordinate (O) (axis cs:1,0,0) coordinate (X)  
          (axis cs:0,1,0) coordinate (Y) (axis cs:0,0,1) coordinate (Z)
          (axis cs:7.5,75,0) coordinate (P)  
          [x={($(X)-(O)$)},y={($(Y)-(O)$)},z={($(Z)-(O)$)},
             canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
          (P) node{\includegraphics[width = 15cm, height = 150cm]{example-image-a}};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```